Movie with identical twin sisters and one has husband murdered and gets her sister imprisioned for the crime
I saw this movie in the 1980s. It could be a TV movie. I don't think it was very good and it seems soapy, but for some reason it has stuck with me except for the title. It is about identical twin sisters who have a strained relationship. One is evil and the other is relatively good.
ES (evil sister) takes GS (good sister) out on a boat. ES fakes her own death by drowning. GS envious of ES's rich lifestyle decides to pretend to be ES for a little while. When she is asked to sign documents, she injures her hand to get out of signing them.
It turns out that ES had put BF1 (boyfriend #1) up to murdering her husband. He is caught and makes a deal to testify against ES. Meanwhile ES has turned up pretending to be GS. GS is arrested and can't prove that she is GS. The handwriting tests indicate that her writing is a brilliant forgery because of her injured hand and ES has mastered GS's handwriting and is determined to be GS.
GS is convicted of murder under her sister's name. GS tells her lawyer that she feels guilty that she got all the good between them and her sister only got evil. The lawyer who it turns out is BF2 goes to see ES who he has working with all along. He tells her what GS said. ES says that "she has always been a little crazy." ES then has BF3 try to kill BF2, but instead BF2.kills BF3 and ES. He then clears GS.

I believe you're looking for the movie Killer in the Mirror 1986.

A woman's truly evil twin steals her sister's wealthy beloved and marries him. After his death, she fakes her own demise and returns from the "dead" to claim her sister's identity--and to frame her for the murder of her husband.

The scene in question where she fakes her own death happens on a boat where she falls in and apparently drowns. While living the rich life the good twin pretends to injure her fingers to get out of signing documents, after failing to practice/ reproduce the signature.
Full movie here:




Thank you this is the movie I've been looking for. I was able to confirm that thanks to the youtube link you provided. Thanks again.

Excellent and happy to help :)
